# discord php curl login Fail

Tags: php, curl, discord

i want to login into discord with php curl but did't work's for me what is the problem in my code i want auto-login into discord and grab data from html ....!
cloed

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? You're going to have to do some diagnostics. Look at the response you're getting. Check for errors.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the grammar.

Comment: i got blank page

Comment: That explains all the exclamation marks. Have you looked in the error log for any clues?

Comment: nope i did't  why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some advices:

1) If you want to see some responsed information. You have to echo `$answer`. Otherwise you couldn't see the response even the data were sent correctly.

2) The site used captcha. I tried it with correct email/password and get the following response `{"captcha_key": ["captcha-required"]}` . I have no idea how to round this. Maybe you should contact the Discord.

3) The site requires json data. Here are the codes I used:

```
<?php
$data = array("email" => "XXXX", "password" => "XXXX");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login');                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$answer  = curl_exec($ch);

echo $answer;

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
?>
```

Hope this will help.