# Discord Post Message To Channel Using cURL - PHP

Tags: php, curl, discord

I am currently trying to post a message on my Discord channel trying to use a cURL POST type. The issue that I am getting when I run my code is that it is giving me a 401 error saying I'm unauthorized. I am running my PHP code on a webserver using xampp localhost. I also went in and tried to authorize my application bot via URL link (https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MYAPPLICATIONID&scope=bot&permissions=8) and have successfully added the bot into my channel. Have a look at my code

```
$data = array("Authorization: Bot" => $clientSecret, 'content' => 'Test Message');                                                                  
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       

$ch = curl_init('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/'.$myChannel.'/messages');                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$answer  = curl_exec($ch);

echo $answer;

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

I get $clientSecret from the application page to reveal my client secret token and $myChannel is my discords channel/server id.

NOTE: I have modeled my code off another stackoverflow answer given here  [discord php curl login Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973528/discord-php-curl-login-fail)  . So I am unsure if I am using the correct syntax for the an application bot

Comment: There are a few things that look wrong here, but since I never used Discord I won't go into it without verifying it more. Though, from a quick Google search (and common API usage exp) I found that you need to pass the Authorization as a header and not inside the body-payload. So try adding `'Authorization: Bot '.$token,` to your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` array instead. (see https://gist.github.com/ianklatzco/c033b33757915feaf48fd0caf14b42cb )

Comment: Fos this authorization, you need to use TOKEN (not clientSecret).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is full code (Without cURL). Just replace the string WEBHOOK_HERE with your bot's webhook:

```
<?php

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $data = ['content' => $message];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        ]
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('WEBHOOK_HERE', false, $context);
?>

<form method="post">
  Type your message here :<br><input type="text" name="message"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm new here so I hope you enjoy the code!

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a tough time searching the web for this, without using webhooks. I wanted to post the message as a bot, not a webhook. The error was with your authorization, as it needs to be in the header... So I'm posting the correct solution here for future googlers.

```
<?php
$myChannel = "CHANNEL_ID";
$myToken = "TOKEN";
$msg = 'Test Message';
$data = array('content' => $msg);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/' . $myChannel . '/messages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Bot ' . $myToken
    )
);

$answer  = curl_exec($ch);

echo $answer;

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close! Your solution has an error.

```
<?php
$myChannel = "CHANNEL_ID";
$myToken = "TOKEN";
$msg = 'Test Message';
$data = array('content' => $msg);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/' . $myChannel . '/messages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Bot ' . $myToken
    )
);

$answer  = curl_exec($ch);

echo $answer;

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
?>
```

I just tested this on my server and it worked. with *Bot ' . $token* it failed.